# ¿Puedo crear una aplicación de monitoreo de integridad de archivos utilizando el stack MERN?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express

Como proyecto de grado debo crear una aplicación de monitoreo de integridad de archivos, es decir la aplicación debe abrir el explorador de Windows/ Linux y cuando se seleccione una carpeta todos los detalles de su contenido se guarde en una base de datos. Todos esos datos almacenados se deben comparar en tiempo real para saber si hay cambios, pero con la condición que el frontend debería ser desarrollado con JavaScript.

Entonces mi pregunta sería: Puedo utilizar el stack MERN para desarrollar la aplicación, es decir usar JavaScript tanto en el cliente como en el servidor o es necesario utilizar otro lenguaje en el backend como seria c# o python.
Se agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda.

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas, checa [ask]

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 por otro lado, cuando tengas puntos que te permitan acceder a la sala de chat, pregunta ahí, es un lugar libre para este tipo de preguntas

Answer (score -1):

Creo que lo que mencionas no es posible.
Mencionas el stack MERN, eso significa que sería una app web, sin embargo hablas de abrir el explorador de windows/linux (¿supongo te refieres al explorador de archivos?). Eso no es posible por restricciones de seguridad de los browsers, a lo más la interacción que se permite es poder subir uno o más archivos, menos aún crear un nexo entre el servidor y los archivos de un cliente para monitorear algún tipo de cambio en tiempo real.
Si tu idea es recopilar esos datos de monitoreo en un servidor, creo que lo mejor sería desarrollar una app que se ejecute localmente en el cliente y envíe datos al servidor.
Si a pesar de esto, insistes en el tema, existe la [Native file system API](https://web.dev/native-file-system/) que está siendo implementada por Google en Chrome, que "*quizás*" pudiese servir para tus propósitos, pero desconozco cuál es su alcance ni tampoco qué tan robusta sea actualmente.